# Overlay перекрывает не цвет текста и всего остального

Tags: css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, frontend

Привет. Подскажите, что сделать. Задача стандартная: есть фоновая картинка, на нее надо наложить затемнение определенного цвета и прозрачности. Оно накладывается. Но проблема в том, что и цвет текста оно меняет. Как решить?

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    }
    
   .wrapper::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00A5BB;
    opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
         Всем привет
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00A5BB;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  Всем привет
</div>
```

Comment: ну быстрый) не успела!)

Comment: Спасибо!) все просто как)

Comment: здесь для быстрого ответа есть кнопка - Копировать код в ответ

Comment: Почему бы не использовать rgba вместо opacity?

Comment: @Ruslan Semenov - в данном случае без разницы, какой вариант использовать